# Groovy: How to set a property/field/def from a method in a groovy script?

Tags: groovy

### Question

Given a simple groovy script (not a class!), how do you set the value of a property/field that is outside a method?

### Example

The following code does not work as expected:

```
def hi;

def setMyVariable() {
    hi = "hello world!"
}

setMyVariable()
assert hi == "hello world!"    //fails
println hi                     //prints null
```

### Failed Attempts

I have tried many things, including the following, which have all failed

...

```
def setMyVariable() {
    this.hi = "hello world!"
}
```

...

```
public void setMyVariable() {
    hi = "hello world!"
}
```

...

```
public String hi;
public void setMyVariable() {
    this.hi = "hello world!";
}
```

### Summary

What is the simplest way to set a variable that is external to a method declaration?  The only thing I can get to work is the following.  There must be an easier way!

```
def hi;

def setMyVariable() {
    this.binding.setVariable("hi", "hello world!")
}

setMyVariable()

println this.binding.getVariable("hi")
assert this.binding.getVariable("hi") == "hello world!"  //passes
assert hi == "hello world!"  //fails
```

Answer (score 4):

In Groovy 1.8.x you can do this:

```
@groovy.transform.Field def hi
```

> Variable annotation used for changing the scope of a variable within a script from being within the run method of the script to being at the class level for the script.

Comment: This sounds like a good way to go. However, when I import `groovy.transform.Field` I get an error that it can't be found. I searched on [Jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.0-beta-2/groovy-all-1.8.0-beta-2.jar!/groovy/transform/Field.class?classDetails=ok) and it seems to be in the "groovy-all" jar. But, apparently, it's not.  I'm using groovy 2.0.  Maybe it's in a different jar?

Comment: import also fails when I use the groovy-all-1.8.4.jar :(

Comment: I also tried adding every jar under `groovy-1.8.4/lib` to the classpath. No dice. Has anyone actually got this working in a script?? I thought this was the best answer but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Strange.. Works for me with groovy-1.8.0 and groovy-2.0.0-beta-1. Something wrong with your IDE?

Comment: I'm running from the command line (via ant task: `<groovy src="PostProcess.groovy" classpath="${classpath.groovy}" />`

Answer (score 4):

You may assign an anonymous function to a variable instead of defining a method:

```
def hi

def setMyVariable = {
    hi = "hello world!"
}

setMyVariable()
assert hi == 'hello world!'
```

Comment: simple. I like this... I'm finding that often in Groovy it's better/easier to use a closure than a method

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that [page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22) of Groovy doc:

> When you define a variable in a script it is always local. But methods are not part of that scope. So defining a method using different variables as if they were attributes and then defining these variables normally in the script leads to problems.

In this case you have to make `hi` part of the binding (easier way would be not to use the `def` actually, so it's gonna be automatically part of the binding).